# Trying to get lists of posts for each categories

Tags: node.js, adonis.js

I am working with AdonisJs and i am trying to get lists of posts associated with a single category.
i have my url like this `http://127.0.0.1:3333/category/news` and my route is like this `Route.get('/category/:slug', 'MainCategoryController.index')`
Anytime i go to the page i get this error

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

I have done the Has Many relationship and also belongsTo relationship on my Post and Category Model

My Post Model is like this

```
category(){
      return this.belongsTo('App/Models/Category')
    }
```

My Category Model is also like this

```
posts(){
      return this.hasMany('App/Models/Post')
    }
```

i also have this in my controller

```
async index ({ params:{slug}, view }) {
      
    const category = await Category.query().where('slug', slug).with('posts').fetch()
      return view.render('category.news', {
        category: category.toJSON()
      })
  }
```

so i am trying to show it in a view like this

```
@each(category in category)
{{ category.post}}
@endeach
```

In my database i have a `category_id` in my Post Table

Comment: Why don't you use `.toString` for result data

Comment: i get this now ```undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined```